# How to create a dictionary from a txt file that contains different categories?

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

If I have a txt file:

```
apple:fruit
banana: fruit
carrot: vegetable
lettuce: vegetable
```

How could I get a dictionary that:

```
{fruit:[apple, banana], vegetable: [carrot, lettuce]}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
file = open("text.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
dict = {}
for line in lines:
    try:
       dict[line.split(":")[1].strip()].append(line.split(":")[0].strip())
    except:
       dict[line.split(":")[1].strip()] = [line.split(":")[0].strip()]
```

i hope this helps you next time before you ask research more about your problem and try some codes on your own so that you can learn more about coding :))

Answer (score 1):

Use collections `defaultdict` to maintain the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

res_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        value, name = line.rstrip().split(':')
        res_dict[name.strip()].append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split(': ') for line in f]
    print({k: [line[0] for line in lines if line[1] == k] for _, k in lines})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to create your own dictionary subclass. One advantage besides not needing to `import` anything that it has over using `defaultdict(list)` is that it prints like a normal dictionary.

```
class Vividict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = list()
        return value


vividict = Vividict()
with open('fruits.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, kind = line.replace(':', ' ').split()
        vividict[kind].append(name)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(vividict, width=40)
```

Output:

```
{'fruit': ['apple', 'banana'],
 'vegetable': ['carrot', 'lettuce']}
```